# Eclipse hangs on Secure Storage Initialization when running SVN commands from Subversive

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I could not run any SVN commands using Subversive (clean, update, etc) with Eclipse Version: 3.7.2, Build id: M20120208-0800. It simply hangs with the command "Secure Storage Initialization". After this, I cannot cancel the operation or close eclipse.

The answer to my problem was that the file in `%USERPROFILE%\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage` had either become corrupted or one of the key-value pairs was causing the failure. I moved the file out of the directory, restarted Eclipse, and everything is working fine, again.

I hate to post a question with an answer, but I couldn't find anything on the web that matched my problem so I thought it might help others.

Comment: I would encourage you to write an answer on this. It simply works, even there's no reference in the internet. Thanks!

Comment: You are [encouraged to post a question and your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Good job.  Next time I suggest posting the solution as an Answer yourself, so you get the credit for any votes.

Comment: This is probably a general Eclipse problem.  We encountered the "Secure Storage Initialization" message and freeze up, but our version of Eclipse is Rational Developer for IBM i, and has no Subversive related plugins.

Answer (score 5):

Just reposting your answer as valid answer:

> The problem was that the file in C:\Users\[user]\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage had either become corrupted or one of the key-value pairs was causing the failure. I moved the file out of the directory, restarted Eclipse, and everything is working fine, again.